# Lebesgue convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(f_k)$ be a sequence of functions in $L$ s.t. $(\int\sum_{k=1}^{m}|f_k|)$ is bounded.  I need to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ converges for a.a.x and if $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ for a.a.x then $f\in L$ and $\int f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int f_k(x)$.
Now I know I have to use either Levi's theorem and some other converge theorems and I have been thinking on it for at least 2 hrs, it still hasnt clicked, any suggestions?
Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a bound for $\int \sum_{i=0}^m |f_i|$. By Fatou's Lemma, 
$$\int \sum_{i=0}^\infty |f_i| \leq \liminf_m \int \sum_{i=0}^m |f_i| \leq C$$

It follows that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty |f_i| \in L^1$.  But $\sum_{i=0}^\infty |f_i|$ is a dominating function for the sequence $\sum_{i=0}^m f_i$, so it follows by the dominated convergence theorem that 
$$\int \sum_{i=0}^\infty f_i = \lim_m \int \sum_{i=0}^m f_i$$

For finite $m$ we may interchange the sum and the integral.  Now just use the definition of an infinite sum to get 
$$\lim_m \sum_{i=0}^m \int f_i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \int f_i$$

Comment: Thank you very much! What does L^1 stand for?

Comment: @Klara The space of functions $f$ for which the integral of $|f|$ is finite.

Comment: Sounded all great to me and I filled in the gaps professor says its totally wrong.

Comment: @Klara Did your professor indicate what the problem was?  I am quite certain that this is correct.  It may be that you need to fill in details (I did omit a few important ones, like the fact that the liminf in the first integral is a limit because infinite sums of positive functions converge monotonically to possibly infinite values), but this proof is standard.

Comment: Maybe I should mention another important details that might be expected: you still need to show that the fact that $\sum |f_i| \in L^1$ implies that $\sum f_i$ converges almost everywhere (this is easy, since the first condition implies that the sum converges absolutely pointwise almost everywhere).

Comment: This is the comment "The major issue here is how to prove the existence of f, in other words, the series is convergent. You need to decompose f into two nonnegative functions like explained on the textbook." I need to understand this since I have an exam tomorrow.

Comment: @Klara My last comment explains it.  The infinite sum of positive functions always exists by monotone convergence, but it might be infinite.  Wherever the sum of the absolute values is finite (which is almost everywhere, since that infinite sum is integrable) the infinite sum of the functions themselves also exists (this is because absolute convergence implies convergence).  If you've developed the integral at all, that last statement is one you have already proven, since an infinite sum is just an integral against the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$